# Get output from ShellScript@2 task into a variable on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is possible get the output from scripts/test.sh and store the value on a variable in a build pipeline, bellow is an example of my YAML:

```
steps:
    - task: ShellScript@2
      inputs:
        scriptPath: scripts/test.sh
```

I searched for a simple solution in this scenario but can't found any one. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [setvariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) logging command inside your shell script:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variableName;]variableValue"
```

Replace the `variableName` with the variable name you want that will be in the pipeline, and `variableValue` with the output you want that will be the value.

In the next steps you can access the variable value:

```
echo "My new variable value is: $variableName"
```

Comment: Hi Shayki ,can you give me an example how can I add the setvariable logging command inside my shell script? could be an simple example inside the shell script like:

#!/bin/sh
echo 'test'

Comment: @WelderPaulo Just add inside your shell script `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variableName;]variableValue"`